# Need help in designing a database with a need of adding new columns or tables dynamically

Tags: database-design

I want to design a vaccination chart for children.

Each child will have his own schedule and history of administered dates.

I am planning to store the administered dates of each vaccine right in the table of children, with each column storing the storing the administered dates of each vaccine. ( like child_chart(child id, vaccine1_administered_date, vaccine2_administered_date, ...)

Now if a new vaccine is found and to be added to chart, I need to make a new column dynamically.

Is it the only way or can I do it in any other way without dynamically creating a column.

This is my first project using databases. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Adding columns and tables dynamically is almost always the wrong approach. Add some sample data to your question and you might get suggestions for a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong table structure planned.

Tip: Naming a series of columns on a table with a sequential number (`foobar1`, `foobar2`, `foobar3`) is often a sign of incorrect database design.

## Many-To-Many

You have children and you have vaccines as entities. Each should be represented by a table.

Furthermore, you have a relationship between those two entities. Each child can get a dose of zero, one, or more vaccines. Each vaccine may be given to zero, one, or more children. That means these two entities have a [*Many-To-Many*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship.

A Many-To-Many relationship is always a problem. The solution is always a third table that bridges the other two tables, representing the relationship between them. The bridging table always has at least two fields; as a child table, it has a foreign key to each of the parent tables.

In your case, the bridging table would be named something like `dose`, tracking which kid got a dose of which vaccine. And in your case, the table would have a third field, the date when the dose was given.

[image: ERD diagram showing patient-dose-vaccine tables]

To present this data together, you perform a [database *join*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) to extract various columns from the various tables where rows match up the foreign key on the child table (`dosage`) to the primary key of each the parent tables (`patient` & `vaccine`).

[image: diagram of data-grid data drawn from the patient-dosage-vaccine tables]

For more discussion of Many-To-Many, search for the canonical example: Books, Authors, and a bridging table named something like Authorship.  Another example is employees being assigned to teams/projects. Yet another example is music albums where an album is categorized one or more genres, and each genre can have many albums assigned to it, as discussed in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49714253/642706).

Also search to learn more about how to separate such data into tables, a process known as [*database normalization*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

> Each child will have his own schedule and history of administered dates.

This Answer addresses only the “history of administered dates” portion of your problem, not the scheduling.

> This is my first project using databases.

Your problem of vaccination records is not simple. As a beginner, I suggest working on a simpler problem.

Comment: Thank you sir, your idea of a bridging table really helped me get a solution. I now got a clear idea about designing tables for these kind of problems.  But sadly, this project was assigned to me and there is no way for me to change my project. I should continue to seek help and practice more solving simpler ones. Thank you sir.